# How to reference a class in a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Really novice question ...

The many apps in my project have a lot of shared code in a gem. I'm trying to add a routine in that gem that will be shared by rake tasks in several apps.

So in the gem lib/utilities directory I have cleanup.rb:

```
module Utilities
  class Cleanup

    def self.perform
      puts "Performing cleanup"
    end

  end
end
```

Then in the app, in lib/tasks, I have cleanup.rake:

```
require "utilities/cleanup"

namespace :mynamespace do
  task :do_cleanup => :environment do
    Utilities::Cleanup.perform
  end
end
```

All I get from rake mynamespace:do_cleanup is "uninitialized constant Utilities::Cleanup".

I've tried several variations of the above. My gems are managed with bundler, but "bundle exec rake ..." gives the same result. I tried using `gem "utilities/cleanup"` instead of require.

(I swear, I tear my hair out trying to figure out how to communicate between modules and classes more than anything else in this language! It's always "which code am I referencing here?" and "why can't it find that class I wrote?")

Comment: Yes, I'm referencing a local directory copy of the gem in the Gemfile. The require doesn't fail.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to write `::Utilities::Cleanup.perform` to explicitly use the top level namespace.